# What is the Terraform format for Okta SAML Cert for resource: okta_idp_saml_key

Tags: terraform, okta, terraform0.12+

I’m trying to terraform script a SAML IdP and running into some issues (besides the fact that the documentation is lacking).

I cannot figure out, for the life of me, the proper format for the x5c attribute in the okta_idp_saml_key script. [Terraform Documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/oktadeveloper/okta/3.6.0/docs/resources/idp_saml_signing_key)

It’s supposed to be base64 format and if I upload the cert to okta via the console, it works fine…

An example cert is like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
….bunch of text…
….bunch of text…
….bunch of text…
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I tried converting it all to base64, tried making it one line with linebreaks, tried doing that and converting to base64.  I then realized that I had the value type wrong in my module, i had it as `string` and it should have been `set(string)`… that got me past my first error and i tried to then set each cert line as an array item, but then i get the below error:

> Error: The API returned an error: Api validation failed: JsonWebKey. Causes: errorSummary: The IDP certificate JWK has an invalid x5c., Status: 400 Bad Request

It makes sense because it ends up putting it out of order in the Terraform plan.

so i set the value like this: `x5c = ["-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----",”text”,”text”, ["-----END CERTIFICATE-----"]`

but the plan comes up like this:

```
+ resource "okta_idp_saml_key" "idp_saml_key" {
  + created    = (known after apply)
  + expires_at = (known after apply)
  + id         = (known after apply)
  + kid        = (known after apply)
  + kty        = (known after apply)
  + use        = (known after apply)
  + x5c        = [
      + "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----",
      + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----",
      + "text",
      + "text",
    ]
  + x5t_s256   = (known after apply)
 }
```

Then, as expected, it gets an error about an invalid cert.  The documentation is the opposite of helpful and I'm basically lost and confused right now...

Has anyone done this before? Any help??

For reference: TF v0.12.31, Okta Terraform v3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some back and forth and help from others, I finally got it working:

```
resource "okta_idp_saml_key" "example" {
  x5c = ["line of textline of textline of text"]
}
```

The key here was removing the carriage returns and line endings and just making it all one line file.

fyi, if you are doing this as a module then:

**# inputs.tf**

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REQUIRED PARAMETERS
# You must provide a value for each of these parameters.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

variable "cert" {
  description = "(Required) base64-encoded X.509 certificate chain with DER encoding."
  type        = set(string)
}
```

**#main.tf for the module**

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REQUIRE A SPECIFIC TERRAFORM VERSION OR HIGHER

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12"
}

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CREATE A SAML CERT KEY
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
resource "okta_idp_saml_key" "idp_saml_key" {
  x5c        = var.cert
}

output "id" {
  value = okta_idp_saml_key.idp_saml_key.id
}
```

**#actual tf file**

```
# #------------------
# CREATE THE OKTA INTERNAL to EXTERNAL SAML IDP
# #------------------

module "org2org_int2ext_idp_saml_key" {
  source = "./modules/idp_saml_key"

  cert = ["line of textline of textline of text"]

}
```